# Onscreen EGL display using NVidia GPU

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, nvidia, egl

I'm trying to use EGL to open an OpenGL context that draws directly on a display connected to an NVidia GPU on Linux.

When opening a EGL display with `eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)`, it seems to create an offscreen rendering context.

Using `eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT`, it does not find any displays.

Is it possible to set it up such that when the program is launched without X11/Wayland (or another process accessing the GPU), it creates a OpenGL context that renders directly on the screen.

Also, it is possible if X11 is set up to access only the primary GPU, make EGL render onto a screen connected to the secondary GPU.

It should give an accelerated OpenGL context, which can then be shared with a CUDA context. The goal is to display an image generated by CUDA kernels as efficiently as possible, without passing through a windowing server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set it up such that when the program is launched without X11/Wayland

NVidia's Linux driver is closely tangled with the X.org infrastructure; it still doesn't properly support Wayland in the way it's supposed to be done. Instead NVidia shoehorned their own "method" to directly access displays, which they called "EGL Stream"; the integration of that with Wayland can be found at https://github.com/NVIDIA/egl-wayland

Technically you can use EGL Streams to directly access the display without an X server.

> Also, it is possible if X11 is set up to access only the primary GPU, make EGL render onto a screen connected to the secondary GPU.

Theoretically this should be possible with EGL Streams, too, assuming you configured the X server to use only that one device you want it to use; this can be done by specifying a BusID in the `Device` section of `xorg.conf`.